# How do I remove a field from a ASN.1 structure (pyasn1)?

Tags: python, asn.1, pyasn1

Basically, I'm looking for something like this:

```
from pyasn1.codec.ber import decoder as ber_decoder
from pyasn1.codec.ber import encoder as ber_encoder

x, _ = ber_decoder.decode(data)
x.remove(2)  # remove the second field
result = ber_encoder.encode(x)
```

Except, obviously, no such function as `remove` exists in the class. `del x[2]` doesn't work either, because the `__del__` function is not implemented.

Comment: how did you solve it?